# Printing alternating characters of a string using Java 8 streams

Tags: java, strings, stream

Given a string, S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N−1, I want to print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line:

> Hacker -> Hce akr

My code works, but I feel it could have been done more elegantly and maybe in a single stream instead of in two... Any ideas how to improve this?

```
private static String reindex(String input) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    IntStream.range(0, input.length())
             .filter(index -> index % 2 == 0)
             .forEach(index -> result.append(input.charAt(index)));

    result.append(" ");

    IntStream.range(0, input.length())
             .filter(index -> index % 2 == 1)
             .forEach(index -> result.append(input.charAt(index)));

    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The main issue with your code is that it operates with [side-effects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) by leveraging the `forEach` operation. If you were to run your code in parallel, it would be broken and you wouldn't have the expected result. In this case, what you want is to use a [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) approach, that is collect elements into a container.

All propose solutions hardcodes the fact that we reindex even and odd indexes. However, it would be possible to make them generic easily.

---

The first simple approach is to use 2 Stream pipeline (as you have done). The first one creates the first part of the String and the second one creates the second. Instead of using `forEach` to add elements to a `StringBuilder`, we collect the elements into a new `StringBuilder`. As such, each index is mapped to the character at that index and accumulated into a new `StringBuilder` with [`appendCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#appendCodePoint-int-). The 3 arguments to the [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) call corresponds to:

1. the supplier of the mutable container, (`StringBuilder::new`);
2. the accumulator of each element into the container (appending the code point of the character);
3. a combiner combining two containers into one (used in parallel processing).

```
private static String reindex(String input) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.length() + 1);
    result.append(filter(input, index -> index % 2 == 0));
    result.append(' ');
    result.append(filter(input, index -> index % 2 == 1));
    return result.toString();
}

private static StringBuilder filter(String input, IntPredicate predicate) {
    return IntStream.range(0, input.length())
             .filter(predicate)
             .map(input::charAt)
             .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);
}
```

The duplicate logic has been extracted to a utility method that filter the indexes matching the given predicate and collects the filtered characters into a `StringBuilder`.

---

But the issue is that it loops around the String two times when such an operation should be possible using a single traversal. This is a bit more complicated to do and I would first measure the performance of the first solution before doing this one: it is possible that your concerned String do not have a length big enough to warrant such an approach.

A possible solution is to collect the elements inside an array of `StringBuilder`. The array to append the current character to is determined by the result of `i % 2`: when `i` is even, this will be 0 and it will append it to the first array; when `i` is odd, it will append it to the second array.

```
private static String reindex(String input) {
    StringBuilder[] result = 
        IntStream.range(0, input.length())
             .collect(
                () -> new StringBuilder[] { new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder() },
                (b, i) -> b[i % 2].appendCodePoint(input.charAt(i)),
                (b1, b2) -> {
                    b1[0].append(b2[0]);
                    b1[1].append(b2[1]);
                }
             );

    return result[0] + " " + result[1];
}
```

Comment: Okay. I see I really need to read up about the collect method since I'm not really understanding what happens inside there in the second approach. Seems like the most concise solution, though I would probably try to refactor some of the lambda expressions into separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add some input validation:

- Can't reindex a string that's `null` throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with a suitable message.
- Can't add a space to the string if its length is already `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, again throw an exception as above.
- Decide if returning a single space is the proper way to handle an empty string.

I would suggest not using streams for this task as they're not really well suited.

Using two simple for-loops, one for even numbers and one for odd, and a `StringBuilder` is very easy to do and understand.

It's also possible to build the result using only a single iteration of the input string.

Here's how I would write it:

```
public static String reindex(String input) {
    if(input == null) {
        throw  new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null");
    }

    int resultLength = input.length() + 1;
    if(resultLength < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input is too long to be reindexed");
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(resultLength);
    //Setting the length to the same as the initial capacity
    //will only update the internal length property and cause
    //no reallocations or updates to other fields.
    //This allows us to use setCharAt in the loop.
    result.setLength(resultLength);

    int separatorIndex = resultLength / 2;
    int startIndexOfOddParts = separatorIndex + 1;
    result.setCharAt(separatorIndex, ' ');

    for (int index = 0; index < input.length(); index++) {
        int isOdd = index % 2;
        int resultIndex = (index / 2) + startIndexOfOddParts * isOdd;
        result.setCharAt(resultIndex, input.charAt(index));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```